# Flutter injecting by ProxyProvider return null

Tags: flutter

[GITHUB SAMPLE PROJECT](https://github.com/MahdiPishguy/proxy_provider_sample)

this is my simple class which i want to inject `WebParserApi` with ProxyProvider and i get null,

```
class RetrievePageSummarizedInformation extends StatesRebuilder {
  BuiltUserProfile builtUserProfile = BuiltUserProfile();
  final WebParserApi _api;

  RetrievePageSummarizedInformation({WebParserApi api}) : _api = api;

  retrievePageProfileInfo(BuildContext context,String username) async {
    //_preparePageProfileCache();
    //WebParserApi _api = Provider.of<WebParserApi>(context);
    return await _api.getProfileRetrieveFromParser(username);
  }

  void _preparePageProfileCache() async {
    await KvStore().createTable('userProfile');
  }
}
```

main function:

```
void main() async {
  Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;

  _setUpLogging();

  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: providers, child: OKToast(child: StartupApplication())));
}
```

`proxyProvider` implementation :

```
List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> providers = [
    ...independentServices, 
    ...dependentServices, 
    ...uiConsumableProviders
];

List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> independentServices = [
  Provider(
    builder: (_) => WebParserApi.create(),
    dispose: (_, WebParserApi service) => service.client.dispose(),
  )
];

List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> dependentServices = [
  ProxyProvider<WebParserApi, RetrievePageSummarizedInformation>(
    builder: (context, api, retrievePageSummarizedInformation) => RetrievePageSummarizedInformation(api: api),
  )
];

List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> uiConsumableProviders = [

];
```

and this is my `WebParserApi` class implementation:

```
@ChopperApi(baseUrl: '/')
abstract class WebParserApi extends ChopperService {
  @Get(path: '{token}')
  Future<Response<BuiltUserProfile>> getProfileRetrieveFromParser(@Path() String username);

  static WebParserApi create() {
    final client = ChopperClient(
        client: http.IOClient(
          HttpClient()..connectionTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 60),
        ),
        baseUrl: 'https://www.sample.com',
        services: [
          _$WebParserApi(),
        ],
        converter: BuiltValueConverter(),
        interceptors: [
          HeadersInterceptor({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
          HttpLoggingInterceptor(),
        ]);
    return _$WebParserApi(client);
  }
}
```

problem is in here. injecting `WebParserApi` to `RetrievePageSummarizedInformation` class:

```
return Injector<RetrievePageSummarizedInformation>(
  models: [() => RetrievePageSummarizedInformation()],
  builder: (context, model) => Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

i created simple project on github on this link https://github.com/MahdiPishguy/proxy_provider_sample in that _api variable of PageInformation class is null when i try to use _pageInformation.pageProfile('test'); in main class

Comment: What is returning null?

Comment: @RémiRousselet in `RetrievePageSummarizedInformation` class `_api` is null

Comment: @RémiRousselet problem is passing `WebParserApi` to `RetrievePageSummarizedInformation ` class constructor as `_api`

Comment: @RémiRousselet could you help me for this ProxyProvider return null?

Comment: You added too much unrelated code. I don't understand what's the issue because of this

Comment: @RémiRousselet i created simple project on github on this link `https://github.com/MahdiPishguy/proxy_provider_sample` in that `_api` variable of `PageInformation` class is null when i try to use `_pageInformation.pageProfile('test');` in main class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem solved, we must use `Provider.of(context)` on class which defined with `ProxyProvider`

```
class RetrievePageSummarizedInformation extends StatesRebuilder {
  BuiltUserProfile builtUserProfile = BuiltUserProfile();
  final WebParserApi _api;

  RetrievePageSummarizedInformation({@required WebParserApi api}) : _api = api;

  getPageProfileInfo(String username) async {
    final res = await _api.getSimpleProfileInformation(username);
    return res;
  }
}
```

injecting solution:

```
models: [() => RetrievePageSummarizedInformation(api:Provider.of(context))],
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having a problem with [`PageInformation _pageInformation = PageInformation();`](https://github.com/MahdiPishguy/proxy_provider_sample/blob/21808c9c13f8f7c42e006a2607b689e6a987c922/lib/main.dart#L34). You probably would better get `_pageInformation` from `context` instead of creating new empty instance by hand where `api` is `null`. This will work:

```
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // here
    Provider.of<PageInformation>(context).pageProfile('test');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

...
```

https://pub.dev/packages/provider#reading-a-value

> The easiest way to read a value is by using the static method `Provider.of<T>(BuildContext context)`. This method will look up in the widget tree starting from the widget associated with the BuildContext passed and it will return the nearest variable of type `T` found (or throw if nothing is found).

Hope it will help.